# Automatically replacing \º with $^\circ$

Tags: fonts, macros

I don't like the º-symbol, that LateX is typesetting, because it has this strange underline.  [image: Degree-Symbol Latex]
So I wanted to make a new-command, that's replacing `\º` with `$^\circ$` and i tried to define it like this in the preambel:

```
\newcommand{\º}{$^\circ$}
```

Unfortunatly what happened, was not what I expected:
My document got extended by a new first page showing the symbol `$^\circ$` and my header, but nothing else. And the position where i actually used the command, completly ignored it, and output just 30 instead of 30º. What am I doing wrong?
EDIT: MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, %openright, 
toc=listof, BCOR=5mm, bibliography=totoc, parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\º}{$^\circ$}
\begin{document}
30º this will give me the output shown in the image.
30\ºthis is supposed to output 30$^\circ$, but doesn't. Instead it produces a new first page showing the symbol $^\circ$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your first error is that you don't give a complete example ... (the code depends beside others on the file encoding and the engine)

Comment: I would use search and replace my favourite editor. Better to use a semantic macro with package `siunitx`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'll add a complete example.
@Johannes_B yes, i could do that. And how do I define the macro correctly using `siunitx`?

Comment: `\SI{30}{\degree}` from `siunitx`

Comment: `º` is not the degree symbol (`°`), but the "masculine ordinal". They look similar in some fonts, but in others the ordinal has the underscore you noticed. The best approach is to use `siunitx` package.

Comment: ok, so using `siunitx` just gives me the correct symbol, right? but how can i make it a correct macro?

Comment: With `utf8` encoding this won't work anyway. You could use `xelatex` and define `\°` then

Comment: You simply need to use the correct input: 5° not 5º that is U+00B0 not U+00BA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `\protected\def` instead of `\newcommand`:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  paper=a4,
  twoside,
  %openright,
  toc=listof,
  BCOR=5mm,
  bibliography=totoc,
  %parskip=half,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\protected\def\º{\ensuremath{^\circ}}

\begin{document}

30º this will give me the output shown in the image.

30\º this is supposed to output 30$^\circ$, and it does.

\end{document}
```

However, you're using the wrong symbol for the degree, because `º` is U+00BA MASCULINE ORDINAL INDICATOR.

[image]

Here's a better way to do what you want:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  paper=a4,
  twoside,
  %openright,
  toc=listof,
  BCOR=5mm,
  bibliography=totoc,
  %parskip=half,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{°}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}

\begin{document}

30° is the right way to go.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the 2nd solution that you provided and it works perfectly. Thank you very much. I still replaced the actual unicode-degree-character with the "masculine ordinal indicator", because that's the one, my keyboard provides, which makes it easier for me. I'm using a MacBook and it doesn't seem to have the real degree-character on its keyboard

Comment: But the `\def` solution will only work once for every starting utf8 byte. An additional `\protected\def\«{blub}` would break it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that's true; but I said that `\º` is the wrong way to go.

Comment: @Max Degree character on mac keyboard is ⌥⇧8.

Comment: @Random832 i gotta correct myself: i have an american-macbook using german keyboard layout. shift+alt+8 will return this ˜ and alt+j returns º, which apparently is the masculine ordinal indicator

Comment: @Max - that's interesting - I don't have access to my mac right now, but I'm sure it's somewhere - have you tried opening the keyboard viewer and looking through all the keys with option and shift-option held down? The US keyboard layout actually has _three_ similar characters - degree on option-shift-8, ordinal on option-0, and ring accent on option-k.

Comment: @Max I think I found a layout image - try ⌥⇧Ü (key label on american physical keyboard is `[`) for degree sign.

Answer (score 4):

With `xelatex` the following command definition works out of the box. The `siunitx` approach is not restricted to `xelatex` of course.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\°}{\si{\degree}}

\begin{document}
30\° or \SI{30}{\degree}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no idea what `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` do, but i have to use them, because my institute says so. Can you provide a solution, that works with these and PDFLaTeX?

Comment: @Max: Nope, `\°` does not work with `utf8` (see Ulrike's answer). You could have written the restriction to `inputenc` etc. in your post, now my efforts are useless :-(

Comment: well sorry, i couldn't know, that those are so important, so i didn't actually mention it explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

You can't define `\º` as º is not a single symbol in utf8. But you can redefine the output of º

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{º}{XXXX}
\begin{document}
30º 
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

And to show that it works with siunitx too:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newunicodechar{º}{\si{\degree}}
\begin{document}
30º
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this actually looks like the solution, but doesn't work unfortunatly. If i use it latex will still output a plain 30 instead of 30º

Comment: My example works. Did you try it exactly as it is?

Comment: no, i replaced the XXXX with `\degree` and added `\usepackage{siunitx}` as you mentioned it before.

Comment: You should really learn how to ask questions. Do you think it is polite to change an answer and then claim that it doesn't work without showing what you did differently?. `\newunicodechar{º}{\si{\degree}}` should work fine if you load siunitx.

Comment: Yes sorry, my bad! Nevertheless the code still doesn't work after changing it.

Comment: As long as you don't show what you are actually doing I can't help you. I won't waste time to guess around.

Comment: Well I just did exactly what you said in your post and in your comment. I just added the lines from your comment to the lines from your post, and it didn't work. But still i can understand you. Thanks for your efforts anyway

Comment: i don't know why yours did not work, but @egreg solved the problem using the same command, you might check that out

Comment: I added an example with siunitx which works fine for me. But you naturally can use whatever definition you want -- that's why I used XXXX to allow you to chose one.

Comment: I got your intention of using the "XXXX" and that's why i didn't mention, that i exchanged it in the first place. Still the example you added is the same thing you added in your comment and unfortunatly it doesn't work in my document and i have no idea why. But since egregs solution works, i just go with that one. Thanks for your efforts i appreciate it!

Comment: If it doesn't work you should try to find out why not - if my example breaks it could indicate that something is wrong in your texsystem.

Comment: Since i'm a first time latex user and though not really familiar with all the packages, the syntax and the commands, i assume that your solution might just collide with one of the packages i use or smth like that. As long as everything else works, i leave it like that since i don't have unlimited time while writing my thesis. In case i'll ever find out what the problem was or if the problem will fix itself via tex live updates or smth i'll let you know.

Answer (score 2):

The `\textdegree` command is available in TS1 encoding without using math mode so:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, %openright, 
toc=listof, BCOR=5mm, bibliography=totoc, parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\newcommand{\º}{$^\circ$}


\begin{document}
30º this will give me the output shown in the image.

30° this will give me thhis.

command names may only use ascii characters, so you can not have a command \verb|\º| in classic latex.


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a different approach, I have found that

```
\usepackage{gensymb}
```

generates a nice degree symbol, all you have to type in the file is

```
\degree
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is to "automatically replace a Unicode character with a macro."

Comment: I know, but I thought it might be a simpler solution in some cases.